# What are the relationships between the notions: binary, interpretation, execution, compilation?

Tags: java, php, apache, compilation, binary

I deeply know that these are basic notions, but I would like to note that we can nowdays be 'web developpers' for years without understanding such mandatory notions (due to ready-made tools like Xampp, Wordpress...). I am giving three situations (among tens) where I encounter these concepts with no full understanding.

**1. According to Wikipedia:**

> a binary data is a data in the binary form (bits and bytes) that
>   cannot be interpreted.

But what is interpretation??

**2. I also heard a time that PHP is:**

> a scripting language, not compiled but interpreted. It does not
>   require any platform to be run.
>
> Unlike Java or C #, you just get PHP binary, and run your script.

**3. What about 'binary distribution' and 'compilation' as invoked in Apache HTTP server official documentation:**

> This documentation assumes that you are installing a binary distribution of
>   Apache. If you want to compile Apache yourself (possibly to help with
>   development or tracking down bugs), see Compiling Apache for Microsoft
>   Windows.

Could someone please give to confused people of the community "once-and-for-all" definitions with examples. Highly invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is as follows:

When used as a noun, *binary* refers to a compiled executable file - this is a file containing machine instructions in non-human readable form, which has previously been compiled, and can be run as an application.

*compilation* is the process of converting human-readable source code into a binary file, so that it can be executed.

*execution* is the process of running a program.

*interpretation* is the process of executing non-compiled code. In some programming languages the human-readable source code is executed directly, without first compiling it into binary machine code.

Comment: No - some languages (eg Java) do not compile source code directly into machine instructions (true 'binary' code) instead they produce bytecode which you can think of as being half way between source code and binary. Bytecode must be run using a suitable application (in the case of Java, the byte code is executed by the Java Runtime Environment) - if you don't have the right application the bytecode is useless.